# как собрать java проект на m1 под винду?

Tags: java, javafx, macos, java-8, m1

Есть проект на java 8 (8u242), с javafx, написано для винды. Можно ли как-то оставаясь в нативной среде, запускать сборку на виндовой среде? желательно через Intellj.

*Паралель* - проблема в том что он может эмулировать на арме, только винду на арме, а на неё нет java8-arm, только с 17-ой.

*VMware* - таже проблема

*UTM* - способен сэмулировать х86_х64, но это настолько медленно, что пока там внутри всё соберётся... в общем ни разу не дождался

*PlayOnMac* - пока не может х64, только х32, как следствие IDE не запускается.

*Wine* - не смог собрать, вроде всё ему нормально но крашится.

*CrossOver* - ближе всех, почти смог, но у него ломается градл, навечно зависает именно градл, при попытке билда

как итог - всё равно придётся запускать как-то на винде, ибо там есть составляющая на С++, ехе, которая является частью программы, но мне не подвластна(УД).

Может кто подскажет, мб какой-то вариант я ещё не попробавл?

Comment: ***Есть проект на java 8 (8u242), с javafx, написано для винды.***-  не понял,  как приложение написанное на  java работает под  windows?

Comment: @Труфальдино java - мультиплатформенная

Comment: Еще раз можно для тех кто в танке.  по каким причинам  у вас не работает java устанавленная  yf VMware?  Что мешает создать образ  на VmWare   и установить на него  java и с++?

Comment: @Труфальдино потому что VMware на M1 может ставить только ARM версию винды, а 8-ой java под ARM не существует

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/jdk-arm-8u6/